# Mysql Case with multiple left outer joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Im experimenting with the following idea. I am trying to build a fallback system all in the single query. Here is some background information:

```
posts_table
id, timestamp

posts_content_table
id, post_id, language_id, title, description
```

The goal here is to query posts_table then in the same query, join the posts_content_table using a fallback system. So if i search for post content with a language_id that doesn't exist it should be able to fallback to an language_id that does contain content. It should allow for multiple levels of fallbacks.

Example:

```
SELECT p.id FROM posts_table AS p 

LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc ON (p.id=pc.post_id AND pc.language_id=1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc2 ON (p.id=pc2.post_id AND pc2.language_id=2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc3 ON (p.id=pc3.post_id AND pc3.language_id=3)
```

Naturally what will happen is when it returns data which is not null, that data should be used as the final result. So this brings me to CASES. How would i implement CASES to work in this way?  Would the following suffice?

```
SELECT p.id, CASE title
WHEN pc.title is Null THEN pc2.title
WHEN pc2.title is Null THEN ps3.title
WHEN pc3.title is Null THEN '-'
END
FROM posts_table AS p 

LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc ON (p.id=pc.post_id AND pc.language_id=1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc ON (p.id=pc.post_id AND pc.language_id=2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc ON (p.id=pc.post_id AND pc.language_id=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose of [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which returns the first non-null of its arguments:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  COALESCE(pc.title, pc2.title, pc3.title, '-') AS title
FROM posts_table AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc ON (p.id=pc.post_id AND pc.language_id=1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc2 ON (p.id=pc2.post_id AND pc2.language_id=2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_content_table AS pc3 ON (p.id=pc3.post_id AND pc3.language_id=3)
```

(Note: I fixed your table aliases - they were all `pc` and I assume you meant to alias as `pc, pc2, pc3`)